# Creating a global array of structs

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

For a project I am working on I need to have a global array of entry structs. I am having trouble though because I can't allocate memory until while running my program I determine the size of a file. The overall goal of this project is to create a word reference. So far how I am doing it is:

```
struct info{
   //stores the specific character
   std:: string c;
   //stores the amount of times a word has come up in the file
   float num;
}
info info_store[];
```

This project is to learn about arrays so I need to use an array

Comment: Use an [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: I forgot to mention I need to use an array

Comment: ... Why? Is this homework or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

**- use new/delete[]**

```
info* p_array=new info[100];  // create an array of size 100

p_array[10].num;  // member access example

delete[] p_array; // release memory
```

**- use std::unique_ptr**

```
std::unique_ptr<info[]> array(new info[size]);
```

-> The advantage is that your memory is automatically released when `array` is destroyed (no more delete[])

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use `std::vector` or any other STL container.

Second,  you can use dynamic arrays.

```
auto length = count_structs(file);
auto data = new info[length];
```

Something like this. Then just fill this array.

Ohh, and make sure you have `delete [] data` to prevent memory leaks.